# postback viewModel is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

i try to search this problem, but could not find a solution for it, **please help me**:

my viewModel:

```
namespace webShop.ViewModels.Home
{
    public class RegisterUserViewModel
    {
        public User User { get; set; }

        public UsersDetaile UsersDetaile { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<state> state { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my model:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }

    public virtual UsersDetaile UsersDetaile { get; set; }
}

public partial class UsersDetaile
{
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Tell { get; set; }
    public bool Gender { get; set; }
    public byte city { get; set; }
    public byte state { get; set; }
    public string postCode { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }

    public virtual City City1 { get; set; }
    public virtual State State{ get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

and my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{ 
    OstanRepository stateRep = new OstanRepository();
    var model = new RegisterUserViewModel();
    model.state = stateRep.Select().ToList();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterUserViewModel user)
{
   //My Code
}
```

and my register view

```
@model webShop.ViewModels.Home.RegisterUserViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", Url = "/Home/Register" }))
{

  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <h1 class="block-header">Register</h1>
      <div class="group">
          <label class="label">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <div class="controls">
              @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.User.Name, new { @class = "text" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.User.Name)
          </div>
      </div>

    //....

  <div class="group">
        <label class="label">Address </label>
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.UsersDetaile.address, new { @class = "text" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.UsersDetaile.address)
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="controls">
             <button class="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

after press submit **user** and **usersDetaile** is ***null***, what can i do?

---

Of course, if i use this acction, it's worke!!!

```
public ActionResult Register(User user)
{
    //...
}
```

i cant find a solution, **PLEASE HELP ME**

Comment: what is the model of your view?

Comment: I think that Its a Binding issue. The default ModelBinder is miss undertanding the type UsersDetaile with the Property. Change the View Model property name UsersDetaile to something else and try again.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong what i see, you have to pass ViewModel to you View, currently you are just passing the `User` property of ViewModel to your view which means your View is strongly typed to `User` type not `RegisterUserViewModel`, thats the reason when you change action parameter to `User` it works:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{ 
    OstanRepository stateRep = new OstanRepository();
    var model = new RegisterUserViewModel();
    model.state = stateRep.Select().ToList();
    return View(model); // pass ViewModel to view not only User Model
}
```

and you view should be strongly type with `RegisterUserViewModel`:

On view set model to `RegisterUserViewModel`

```
@model webShop.ViewModels.Home.RegisterUserViewModel
```

Answer (score 1):

The binding fails because you POST method parameter is named `user` and your model (`RegisterUserViewModel`) contains property with the same name (`public User User { get; set; }`)

Change you method signature to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterUserViewModel model)
```

and the properties will be correctly bound. Alternatively, you can change the property name but this would mean updating your view code

```
`public User Person { get; set; }`
```